# React hooks without initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a project where I am fetching some data from an API and storing it as a JSON object in a state hook. However, when initialised with `const [data, setData] = useState([])`, obviously, `data` stores an initial value of `[]` before fetchAPI passes in the correct values, which is causing all sorts of problems on the functionality because my functions cannot work on empty objects.

I have tried sleep methods, async/await functions but it all comes down to me having to initialise that state. Components look like this:

```
// fetchHook.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fetchUrl() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);

  return [data, loading];
}

export { useFetch };
```

and it is imported on main App component which then passes the `data` as users to another component like so:

```
// App.js
import { useFetch } from "./components/fetchHook";


function App() {
  const [users, loading] = useFetch("https://api.github.com/users");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Profiles users={users} count={count} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I make sure that fetch method always returns valid data before returning the initial state?

Comment: *"How can I make sure that fetch method always returns valid data before returning the initial state?"* You can't, but presumably that's why you have `loading`, so the consumer component knows that the data is still loading. So...?

Comment: It's fairly common to use `null` to mean "no data" in this sort of situation. I'd use that as the initial state of `data`, rather than `[]`, not least because what you fetch may not be an array. But you still need the `loading` flag, because "no data" could mean "no data yet" or "no data because of an error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical solution is to check `error` and `loading` and render appropriate:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      loading ? <Loading/> :
      <div className="App">
        <Profiles users={users} count={count} />
      </div>
    )
  )
```

API typically return both error and loading status. For example design of apollo return object with fields included names `error` and `loading`

But in projects we can simplify as we like. For example we can return status field where both error an loading is packed:

```js
  const [users, status] = useFetch("https://api.github.com/users");
  return status ? <Loading {...{status}}/> :
    <div className="App">
      <Profiles users={users} count={count} />
    </div>
```

Pretty much ideas about API design you can found in [this discussion](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2539#issuecomment-465719599)